# How to return values from a parameterized List<string> (int number, List<string> lines)

Tags: c#

How can I return a list of strings and execute the return **without printing them out?** The function takes them and re-arrange them in lexicographical order. My solution prints them out. I tried the following:

```
public static List<string> paragraph(int number, List<string> lines)
    {
        var words = lines.ToArray();

        var sort = from x in words
                   orderby x
                   select x;

        foreach (var item in sort)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        return null;            
    }
```

The only solution I could find was to print them out. I can see the result. But how can I stored the `item` that goes thru the loop and print them out in the main method? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking? You want to sort `lines` and return the sorted list as a separate list?

Comment: If you don't want to print them, remove the `Console.WriteLine` call.

Comment: Are you saying you want to execute the LINQ query? `sort.ToList()` will do that. But Rufus makes a valid point: It's the `foreach` that realizes the query, not WriteLine(). Or are you saying you want to return `sort` instead of `null`?

Comment: What do you want exactly - this is quite a bunch of nonsense. What makes words from lines? Do you want to return all _words_ in lexicographical order from all lines?

Comment: Also, what is the `int number` parameter for? It's not used in the code.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to output the results inside the method, it can be reduced to one line: `return lines.OrderBy(line => line).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bunch of unnecessary work going on in your original code.  This is all you need to sort your original list with linq and return it.

```
public static List<string> paragraph(int number, List<string> lines)
{
    return lines.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
}
```

edit:  fixed a missing arrow and simplified

Answer (score 3):

You are printing each line in the

```
foreach (var item in sort)  {    Console.WriteLine(item);    }
```

Block
Remove the for loop and return "sort.ToList()" like

```
return sort.ToList()
```

Comment: that's still unnecessary code.  He'll be copying lines into words instead of just using linq on lines

Comment: That is correct, but doing it in the method would Change the original list as they are passed by reference. If it is what is intended the function could be void, but that would "confuse" someone using this method externally as the method is public.

Comment: `OrderBy` does not affect the original list - it returns a new `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, so it's safe to do `return lines.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

I interpret your question as:

> *How can I take a list of strings and re-arrange them in lexicographical order and return them without printing them out?*

If that's the case, you can just call `OrderBy` to order the lines, and then return the result of calling `ToList()`, which realizes the query:

```
public static List<string> GetOrderedLines(List<string> lines)
{
    return lines?.OrderBy(line => line).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a vague guess based on the name of the variables used (sort of intellectual reverse-engineering) - probably not what OP wants, but it is clear that he/she wants something else than what she/he asked for.

```
public static List<string> Words(int number, List<string> lines)
{
    var separators = new[] {',','.',';',' ','\n','\r'};
    return lines
                .SelectMany(l => l.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) // take all words from all lines
                .Select(w => w.ToLowerInvariant()) // make them lowercase
                .Distinct() // remove duplicates
                .OrderBy(w => w)  // lexicographical ordering
                .Take(number) // just to use the int parameter
                .ToList() // materialize result             
}
```

Comment: you seem to be treating each entry in the line as its own list.  It will probably work but it's way above and beyond what he asked for.